# Why does Principal Component is in direction of maximum variance?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics

What does the variation data in the context of Principal Component Analysis refer to? I mean suppose we have 5 features or we can say that 5 dimensions then variation in data will be what? Means, Does it refers to the variation of data in every feature?And why PCA is in direction of maximum variation in data?

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22569/pca-and-proportion-of-variance-explained) answer from Cross Validated provides excellent answer to your questions.

On top of that, to answer *And why PCA is in direction of maximum variation in data?*, I suggest reading some basic on information theory, [this blog article](http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-09-Visual-Information/) delivers a great introduction to the subject. To give a tangible example, imagine that among your 5 features you have a vector that is all ones. It's intuitive that it does not help you; all samples share the same feature. The variance of this particular feature will be zero - it bears no information. Zero entropy, a perfect order if you will, means nothing ever changes along given direction: a clear candidate to be dropped from the data. Increase variance = increase information content.